# C/C++ : What is the right gSoap command line to generate web service from WSDL?

Tags: c++, http, soap, service, gsoap

I have a WSDL that I must respect to generate the Web Service (SOAP/HTTP) in C/C++.

For this I'm using gSoap. I find there is this command `wsdl2h` but I don't see the right parameters to generate the service and not the client.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL2H command is used to generate a c/c++ header file from a WSDL schema file, after you've got the .h file you will need to use the soapcpp2 command to create the server code.

I'd suggest you read the gsoap docs [here](http://www.genivia.com/products/gsoap/documentation.html); especially sections 7.2, 8 and 9.